# Add all files by default to Visual Studio with TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Is there a way to not exclude any files by default? I add many files and sometimes forget the "Add items to folder" step. This was one thing that was easier with SVN b/c it assumed that anything you added to your project folder was part of the project. Annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TFS2012, you can [use a Local Workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb892960.aspx):

> When you use a local workspace, you get the following advantages:
>
> …
>
> Visual Studio automatically detects changes. When you add or delete
>   files outside of Visual Studio, the program automatically detects
>   these changes.

Comment: You still have to check for any detected changes and add those manually. New files are not automatically added to your pending changes.

Comment: I have too many files to use a local workspace, but isn't there an "Detected" section under "Excluded Changes" which lists the adds?

Comment: @stuartd Too many files to use a local workspace?  How many files do you have?  Gigabytes worth?  Terabytes?

Comment: @EdwardThomson the recommended limit for a local workspace is 100,000 files, above which performance degrades too much. My workspace based on our source tree has ~150,000 files in it.